# Regex, replace all words starting with @

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression that puts all the words that starts with @ into span tags.
I've accomplished what is needed but i'm not sure that i completely understand what i did here.

`content.replace(/(@\S+)/gi,"<span>$1</span>")`

1. The () means to match a whole word, right?
2. The @ means start with @.
3. The \S means "followed by anything until a whitespaces" .

But how come that if don't add the + sign after the \S , it matches only the first letter?

Any input would be appreciated .

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\S` is any non-whitespace character and `a+` means **one or more of a**. So

`@\S` -> An @ followed by **one** non-whitespace character.

`@\S+` -> An @ followed by **one or more** non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 3):

Sharing code to change hashtags into links

```js
var p = $("p");
var string = p.text();

p.html(string.replace(/#(\S+)/gi,'<a href="http://twitter.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Test you code here  #abc #123 #xyz</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
content.replace(/(@\S+)/gi,"<span>$1</span>")
```

`(@\S+)` is a capturing group which captures `@` followed by 1 or more (`+` means 1 or more) non-whitespace characters (`\S` is a non-whitespace character)
`g` means global, ie replace all instances, not just the first match
`i` means case insensitive 
`$1` fetches what was captured by the first capturing group.

So, the `i` is unnecessary, but won't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(@\S+)gi/

1st Capturing group (@\S+)
    @ matches the character @ literally
    \S+ match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
g - all the matches not just first
i - case insensitive match
```

Answer (score -1):

> The \S means "followed by anything until a whitespaces" .

That's not what `\S` means. It's "any character that's not a whitespace", that is, *one* character that's not a whitespace.