# Regex that finds all words starting with single or double quote only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to find in a text all words that starts with `'` or `"` single or double quote (hence like english contractions) like `em` or `bar` in

```
I love 'em
foo 'bar
foo 'bar?
foo 'bar.
```

but ignoring words surrounded by double quotes or single quotes like

```
foo "bar"
foor 'bar'
```

Now, a regex to find those last ones is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310574/regex-replace-all-words-starting-with) one

```
// find words in double or single quotes
/\"([^\"]+)\"|'([^']+)'|\\S+/
```

but how to find words starting only with `'` or `"`, ignoring the last punct like word `foo` in `'foo?` or `'foo.`, etc. plus the double or single quoted words?

Comment: Maybe `/["']([^\s'"]+)\b(?!['"])/g`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0w66aT/2). Or `/["']([^\s'"]+)\b(?![^\s'"]*['"])/g`. Do you want to match `'foo.bar` fully or just `'foo`?

Comment: All words like `'foo` or `"foo`, but not within double or single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the `'` or `"` with a character set of `["']`. Capture that character set in a group so you can backreference it later. Repeat word characters, then match a word boundary, with negative lookahead for the first captured group (`(?!\1)`), ensuring that the next character after the end of the word is *not* the same `'` or `"` that was matched at the beginning.

```
(['"])\w+\b(?!\1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/d5l2ol/2

Note that this permits inconsistent quotes such as

```
foo "bar'
```

(if you don't want that, just repeat the `['"]` character set again in the negative lookahead, rather than a backreference)

Comment: amazing, that's it. Also it general because I can even add more beginning chars, thank you! In the case of `"foo \"bar'".replace(/([`'"])\w+\b(?!\1)/g,'')` in fact I get the single remaining `'`.

Comment: I did not realize that this regex will cut away all words starting with `'` or `"` so it will capture event apostrophes like `d'écrire`, so I will have `"Poètes essayant d'ecrire".replace(/([`'"‘])\w+\b(?!\1)/g, '') = Poètes essayant d`, while I would keep these terms, but only capturing words starting with `'` or `"`.